# Ruby Passenger: no such file to load bundler

Tags: ruby, rubygems, passenger, ruby-enterprise-edition

I installed Phusion Passenger with Nginx, configured Nginx to point to the right directory, Then I ran webapp directory and this has downloaded the gemfiles, but it can't find the gems.

When I visit the site I get the standard Passenger error page which says:

```
Error message:
no such file to load -- bundler
```

Here's the full error: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=vpx36r&s=7

I've do a `gem install bundler` so I know bundler is installed, but I think it's looking in the wrong place for the gems.

It appears as if Passenger has installed ruby-enterprise-1.8.7 and it looks like 1.8 was already installed in this box.

gem env gives me the following:

```
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.4.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2009-12-24 patchlevel 248) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /opt/local/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /opt/local/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /opt/local/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
      - ruby
      - x86_64-linux
    - GEM PATHS:
      - /opt/local/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
 - /root/.gem/ruby/1.8
    - GEM CONFIGURATION:
       - :update_sources => true
       - :verbose => true
       - :benchmark => false
       - :backtrace => false
       - :bulk_threshold => 1000
    - REMOTE SOURCES:
       - http://rubygems.org/
```

From what I've read it appears to be a path issue, but I don't know what the best course of action is to fix it.

Here's the output of

which ruby:

```
/opt/local/ree/bin/ruby
```

which bundle:

```
/opt/local/ree/bin/bundle
```

I've run bundle install in that directory and it's given me:

```
Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
```

Comment: what error do you receive? and when?

Comment: "Error message:
no such file to load -- bundler" I've also updated the question

Comment: ok, check these: 1) where you installed ruby (run: which ruby) and gem (which gem); 2) check for bundler (which bundler); 3) cd into app and run "bundle install"

Comment: I've added those details to the question.

Comment: What does your nginx config look like?

Comment: @Dogbert Here's my nginx config https://gist.github.com/7d10a26e40aa4d8b68a1

Comment: and `ls /opt/local/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/`

Comment: It seems like you have two Ruby installs, one at `/opt/local/ree`, and one at `/opt/local/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it looks like you have some path issues (as you already stated). try to check *why* you have two different paths for your ruby installation.

I mean, according to your gem env output, you have some installation on

```
 /opt/local/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/
```

but you also have ruby and bunlder under

```
/opt/local/ree/
```

so, start from here to check if all the paths are correct and/or you haven't any double installations (well, it's just enough to check if your ENVs are coherent).

Another issue could be related to your nginx.conf, you should have something like this:

```
[...]
 http {
  passenger_root /your/path/to/passenger/gem;
  passenger_ruby /path/to/ruby;
  [...]
 }
```

**UPDATE** (just saw additional comments with nginx.conf):

as you can see, there's a problem with paths: you have two paths for ruby and gems installs:

```
/opt/local/ruby-enterprise....
```

and

```
/opt/local/ree
```

you should remove the latter (not phisically, just review ENVs to point to the first one)

EDIT:
to change your env, you can append the following line to your */etc/bash.bashrc* (or whaterver file is loaded from your shell by default):

```
PATH="/opt/local/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/bin:$PATH"
```

then logout and login, or for a quick test, launche this command from shell:

source /etc/bash.bashrc

now, retry to see what binary is used by default with:

```
which ruby
which gem
which rake
gem env
...
```

everything should have the */opt/local/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/* prefix (that's what is used from nginx and passenger configs).

**UPDATE2**: from the comments, it turned out that you have at least 3 ruby installs:

- ruby from your package manager in /usr/lib/ruby/ (are you using ubuntu linux?)
- a ruby in /opt/local/ree/
- a ruby in /opt/local/ruby-enterprise-....

at this point, the best thing to do is:

- uninstall all the rubys under /opt/local/ and all their gems
- uninstall (purge) system provided ruby packages (you don't need it)
- install and setup RVM: https://rvm.io
- re-install passenger using RVM: https://rvm.io/integration/passenger/
- fix nginx.conf to use passenger path and ruby

Comment: I've edited /etc/bashrc presume that the same file by another name? Running: which ruby, which rake and which gem return the /opt/local/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/... but 'gem env' still contains two gem paths the correct one and /root/.gem/ruby/1.8 :/

Comment: the second one should not be a problem. have you tried to see if it works now?

Comment: Yep, still get the same error as before 'no such file to load -- bundler' I've restarted nginx in case that was an issue.

Comment: @andrea yep, 'bundler (1.0.15)' Could it be a permissions issue?

Comment: look at the backtrace: it's still looking in /usr/lib/ruby/*. I don't know how you installed ruby and why you have at least 3 ruby environments without using RVM

Comment: updated my answer (see UPDATE2) with a drastic solution, but it should work

Comment: trust me, it's the best choice for ruby development. also, keep in mind that default ruby packages are a bit crappy: whatever linux packaging you pick, they're quite unusable :/

Comment: RVM worked out very well, it does an extra layer of complexity, but it actually works!

Comment: indeed, RVM is complex in order manage several ruby installs, but (imho) it's the best way to go.